# Difficulties with flood fill in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, flood-fill

I made this program that should flood fill the matrix but something went wrong. Here's the code:

```
queue<Point> Qu;    
int n,m;
cin>>n>>m;
int mat[n][m];
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)    
    for(int j=0;j<m;++j)
        cin>>mat[i][j];        

Point N,W,S,E,bgn;
bgn.x=0;
bgn.y=0;
Qu.push(bgn);
while(!Qu.empty()){
    N.x=Qu.front().x-1; N.y=Qu.front().y;
    S.x=Qu.front().x+1; S.y=Qu.front().y; 
    E.x=Qu.front().x; E.y=Qu.front().y+1; 
    W.x=Qu.front().x; W.y=Qu.front().y-1;

    if(mat[N.x][N.y]==0){mat[N.x][N.y]=2;Qu.push(N);} 
    if(mat[S.x][S.y]==0){mat[S.x][S.y]=2;Qu.push(S);} 
    if(mat[E.x][E.y]==0){mat[E.x][E.y]=2;Qu.push(E);} 
    if(mat[W.x][W.y]==0){mat[W.x][W.y]=2;Qu.push(W);}    
    Qu.pop();
}


for(int i=0;i<n;++i){    
    for(int j=0;j<m;++j)
        cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";        
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Point is a struct I defined earlier in code and it contains only x and y as integers. The program fills the matrix correctly if it's empty e.g. :
If i enter

```
3 3
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

I get the output :

```
2 2 2
2 2 2
2 2 2
```

But if i enter:

```
3 3
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

I get

```
2 2 1
2 1 2
2 2 1
```

instead of

```
2 2 1
2 1 0
2 2 1
```

If I check the coordinates after every pop, I can notice that it goes out of boundaries ( e.g. it returns the coordinates 1 -1 and it shouldn't do it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the coords of N,W,S and E, even if they are invalid; for example if you start at (0,0) and do this:

```
N.x=Qu.front().x-1; 
N.y=Qu.front().y;
...
if(mat[N.x][N.y]==0) {
    mat[N.x][N.y]=2;
    Qu.push(N);
}
```

N will be (-1,0). Instead you only check a direction if you are not at the border of the matrix. For example for N you could do:

```
if(Qu.front().x > 0) {
    N.x=Qu.front().x-1; 
    N.y=Qu.front().y;
    if(mat[N.x][N.y]==0) {
        mat[N.x][N.y]=2;
        Qu.push(N);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You may also like to read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6017/QuickFill-An-efficient-flood-fill-algorithm

Comment: This didn't make any change since i'm only adding a Point to the queue if the value at that point is zero. I don't know why the programs ads it to queue anyway ..

Comment: @LoadExcite The problem is that mat[-1,0] might be zero. It is undefined what the result is, so it can be any value including zero. Most c++ implementations will probably use the address of mat[3,2] when you try to read mat[-1,3]. And that is exactly why your mat[3,2] gets filled. If your array is [3,3] you simply must not use any index lower than 0 or larger then 2, because the result will not be what you expect.

Comment: I gave the example for N, the same must be done for W, S and E, just the condition is different there.

Comment: I did it right ..didn't work but I extended the matrix  by rows and columns of 1 at every side and solved the problem. Since you gave me the idea, your post is the answer :) Thanks.